# ClickOnce Deployment for two projects each has its own configuration file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, app-config, configuration-files

I am using VS 2010 SP1.

I have two projects:

- POS (WPF application)
- Sync (Console application)
- Lib (Class libray)

I added the Sync and lib assembly as a reference to the POS project. In runtime, The POS application runs the Sync application using Diagnostics.Process.Start().

During development everything works perfectly as expected, but when publishing the POS application using ClickOnce, I find that **POS.exe.config.deploy** is published and the **Sync.exe.deploy**, but
the problem is that the **Sync.exe.config.deploy** is not published.

I went to Solution Explorer and changed the **Build Action** to **None/Content** and **Copy to output directoy** to **Copy If Newer/Do not Copy**.

Comment: Aren't this three projects?

Comment: Yes they are, but the Lib has no config files. And I don't have problems with Lib project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you getting the ClickOnce deployment to include Sync.exe? You must have a linked reference to the exe, is that right?

To C/O, Sync.exe is a secondary assembly, and it doesn't know about the config file. You're going to need to add a reference to the config file to the POS project. To do this, make sure you're building Sync.exe first, build it, then add a reference to the config file in the \bin\Release folder. You can try adding it to the POS project as a linked reference so it picks it up each time. If that doesn't work, you might have to just copy it over to the POS project and include it directly.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up by copying it over the POS project.